# Django execute code on session expire

Tags: django

I have implemented `SESSION_EXPIRE_ON_BROWSER_CLOSE` setting in my django application. I have a `model A` that is tied to the session key of current user session. So, when the user closes the browser session expires, how can I configure a `Signal`(or any other way) to update `model A`?

Answer (score 0):

No. Session expiration is not an event, and the server knows nothing about when it happens.

Comment: Well, is it recommended that when a new session for user is created all the previous sessions be purged?